# View DNS requests with Python 3 fails

Tags: python, dns

As far as I know, DNS requests and responses take place on port #53 UDP.

I've written this small script, which creates and binds an udp server to port 53 and it's listening for incoming data.

```
udp_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
udp_server.bind(("0.0.0.0", 53))
print("[!] UDP server binded.")

while True:
    data, addr = udp_server.recvfrom(1024)
    print(data)
```

In order to test it, I opened Chrome and enter a site (eg. www.google.com), but the program didn't print something. Firstly, I thought it was a matter of the site, but after entering several sites this time, the results had no change.

Clearly I am missing something, but my knowledge isn't enough to find what is it. Could you help me?

Comment: What OS?  What is your network configuration?  Did the page load?  If so, your browser is probably going to the DNS server given to it by your network, not localhost.  Also, you could be using a different kind of server.  Maybe you should "peek" with Wireshark?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise 32 bit, Python 3.4.2. I am using my wireless onboard card (laptop). The pages loaded as expected. Wireshark is a solution, but I'll go to it as soon as Python is proved that it can't do it. I feel way more comfortable with Python, plus this will be the base of something bigger; if it will ever work.

Comment: For Windows, type "ipconfig /all" at a command prompt to see how your laptop was configured.  If "DNS Servers" doesn't list "localhost" first, it is probably using that IP address instead of localhost.  You probably need to override the network configuration to not use DHCP settings for DNS and use localhost instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I had to configure my wifi's adapter DNS servers, I set "127.0.0.1" as the primary server. Data now is shown.